# link_to append parameter using javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know that in rails 2.3 there is :with option available with link_to form helper. The use of it is basically the append parameters to URL. But in rails 3.1 its not working, how can i append more parameters to path using link_to in rails 3.1. Here is how it worked in rails 2.3

I need to append to my path something i get from javascript.

```
<%= link_to "Edit", {:url => error_prone_teacher_students_path(@store), :remote => true, :with => "'id='+$('#id').val()", :method => :get}, :id => "load", :style=>"display:none;" %>
```

Comment: can you write your desired output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically insert params to link\_to in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145330/dynamically-insert-params-to-link-to-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 no more support this behaviour  you have to create the form to submit value.

Comment: yes, i figured it out, i will accept your answer so that others dont get stuck like i did

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<%= link_to "Edit", error_prone_teacher_students_path(@store) + "?id=parameter", :remote => true, :method => :get, :id => "load", :style=> "display:none;" %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi RSB, $F('id') is coming from javascript. i need to append a a parameter from javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
link_to "EDIT", error_prone_teacher_students_path(@store, q1: 1, q2: 2)
```

Comment: Hi, i need to append a parameter which is generated by Jquery

Comment: Then I guess, u need to append it runtime.  may be like this. I m assuming u r getting a value in a variable. `$("#link_id").attr(href, ($("#link_id").attr('href')+ "?id="+value))`

Comment: Here is a good reference, in case u have jquery object which u want to convert and append. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object